# Has anyone encountered this bug in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Uncaught error in actionCallback : Cannot read property 'relation_map' of null

If yes, how were you able to fix it?
Many thanks

Comment: Please post relevant code or it will be very difficult or impossible to assist you.

Comment: This looks like in your action callback, you reference relation_map off an object, which you expect to be valid but which is in fact null. Post the code for your action callback and we should be able to tell you what happened.